# extract selected cells from a custom format in excel

Tags: excel

[image]
I want to extract all the party names and their remaining amount in two columns in a different sheet so that I can easily perform data analysis on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Filter ColumnB to select "Total for Party" then select ColumsC:D copy and paste into a new sheet.